# How to select with Multiple values from Aerospike (GOlang)?

Tags: go, aerospike

(Solution)

If you want to query like MYSQL in aerospike with multiple values

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <value1> = 1 and <value2> = 2
```

then you can use [Predicate Expressions](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#PredExp)

example.

```
fetchSocialActionStmt := aero.NewStatement("testnamespace",
    "binname")

predExp := []aero.PredExp{}

predExp = append(predExp,

    aero.NewPredExpIntegerBin("value1"),
    aero.NewPredExpIntegerValue(1),
    aero.NewPredExpIntegerEqual(),


    aero.NewPredExpIntegerBin("value2"),
    aero.NewPredExpIntegerValue(2),
    aero.NewPredExpIntegerEqual(),

    aero.NewPredExpAnd(2))
    _ = fetchSocialActionStmt.SetPredExp(predExp...)                               
    likes, err := as.Client.Query(nil, fetchSocialActionStmt)
```

Comment: Is this a question, or an answer?

Comment: what's the issue you are getting? If you have any issue with query related in aerospike you can refer docs: https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/querying_records.html

Comment: Both, i had question then i googled but no solution found so i added here with solution after reading docs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.